# How to enumerate key value pairs of a bundle

Tags: android, bundle, enumeration

Does anyone know of a way to enumerate all of the key value pairs of a bundle without knowing ahead of time all the keys?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the only way to get all they key-value pairs is to enumerate through keys using `keySet()` and then `get()` its relative value. For example:

```
for(String key : bundle.keySet()){
    Object obj = bundle.get(key);   //later parse it as per your required type
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Follow up question - how would you get the bundle obj for an xml resource.  There is no get for xml and getString returns null?

Comment: to get data out from xml, you may use `XmlPullParser`. For example, read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)